Eclipse Maven dose not work with javafx dependencies
I'm trying to convert a existing JavaFX project to a Maven project. The problem I'm running into is, that I get a error if I try to add one of these dependencies:
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>21.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>22.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

The problem only occurs if I put in a version above 16.
I'm using java 17 and eclipse version 4.32.0.
Thanks for your help in advance.
I have not worked with Maven before so OI don't really now how to troubleshoot this.
Edit
The pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>GameClientGUI</groupId>
    <artifactId>GameClientGUI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>HelloFX</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


What is the error?

When I hover over it: org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:jar:${javafx.platform}:17 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
